pyplot.plot uses markerfacecolor while pyplot.scatter uses facecolor
I come from a Matlab background, which is an inspiration for matplotlib (or so I understand, rightly or wrongly).
I was surprised to find that similar options for the different plots use different option names.  For example, pyplot.plot uses markerfacecolor while pyplot.scatter uses facecolor.
In Matlab, such options are common across plots.  I'm wondering how the differences arose in matplotlib.pyplot.  Are the different plots developed by different groups?

Quoting Tim Hoffmann from some GitHub issues :

"The relation between plot and scatter is messy for historic reasons, partly originating even from MATLAB ... We only have very limited possibilities to change the API and naming due to backward-compatibility."
[Source] : GH27765


"Background: The reason for the difference is that plot() creates a Line2D, which can have markers on the data points and/or lines connecting these. Therefore edgecolor would be ambiguous for plot(). In contrast, scatter() has only markers and thus edgecolors is sufficient. It may or may not have been an intentional design. Additionally, scatter() can color each marker individually. That's why it uses the plural edgecolors. Even though they have some overlap, plot() and scatter() have distinct sets of functionality, which shines through in their API. ... Note also that it doesn't stop at mec. This applies to all marker* parameters of plot(). ... In summary, it is unfortunately not possible to make the APIs of plot() and scatter() more consistent. That ship has sailed long ago during the design of LineCollection. Any attempt to make them appear more similar will only result in other differences to be more prominent."
[Source] : GH20361


Wow.  Talk about the burden of past decisions.  Thank you for that background.

Actually, that answer provides some historical background, but doesn't explain how (say) MarkerFaceColor wasn't deliberately adopted in scatter plots for the sake of consistency.  For that to happen would require a deliberate effort at harmonization across plot types.  This is why I speculated that such harmonization didn't occur during development.  However, it doesn't stop the scatter method from adopting (say) markerfacecolor as an alias for facecolor, which would avoid breaking backward compatibility.  I may suggest this on the GitHub page you cited.
